# parse error near `unset' using zsh/iTerm2 on OSX El Capitan

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, zsh

So I installed `zsh` and `iTerm 2` and every time I open `iTerm 2` I get this message:

`/Users/jeitnier/.rvm/scripts/rvm:81: parse error near 'unset'`

Searching Google takes me [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1749) and [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1351#issuecomment-10939525).

I figure editing `.zshrc` and any other `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` & `.profile` files and ensuring any `export PATH` calls are wrapped with `$PATH` would fix it, but it doesn't.

I've reinstalled `rvm` by: `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles`.

Nothing works. What else can I try?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to change `$PATH` in as few places as possible, e.g. `~/.profile`. From looking at the [source](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/rvm#L81) the error is not obvious. You could run `zsh -x` to see the lines executed up until the error to allow debugging. But it's probably best to ask in the [rvm Issue tracker](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues).

Comment: This had nothing to do with my path. I was using a reserved bash word "do" as an alias.

Comment: Hah, that's a tricky one,  shells offer plenty of freedom to shoot oneself in the foot. glad you sorted it out :)